# Bundle with RVM. ruby not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I installed Ruby using RVM but, I'm having trouble using bundler.

```
$ bundle -v
/usr/bin/env: ruby: File or directory not found
```

Other commands works:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.8
$ gem -v
1.8.24
```

Can anyone help me?
Some other informations that can help you help me:

```
$ which ruby
/home/gabriel/.rvm/bin/ruby
$ which bundle
/home/gabriel/.rvm/bin/bundle
$ which rails
/home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rails
$ gem list | grep bundle
  bundler (1.2.0)
  rubygems-bundler (1.0.7)
$ rvm -v
  rvm 1.15.8 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

My path in .bashrc is configured like this:

```
GEM_HOME="/home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
GEMGLOBAL_HOME="/home/gabriel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"

export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin:$GEMGLOBAL_HOME/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin:$MONGODB_HOME/bin
```

I'm newbie with ruby, someone can help me? Thanks alot. Have a nice day =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use default for loading ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --defaut
```

and using a login shell in your terminal rvm will automatically take care of setting up environment

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gnome Terminal, you have also to set "Run command as login shell" in "Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and command".
If you don't do that, rvm use command will not works